# DIV side by side without wrap

Tags: html, css, charts

i got a little problem with my chart.

I have a fixed container, `.gantt-chart`
in this container is one row `.gantt-row`.
in this row are two wrapper(`.gantt-columns-wrapper`, `.gantt-sub-columns-wrapper`) to layering the columns with absolute position

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
```

in the wrapper are the columns and the sub-columns.
I want to scroll but they are wrapped down? Any solution for this?

### the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xhy28kop/1/)

[image: How it should look]

Comment: The overflow on .gantt-chart is hidden, that makes that you can't scroll.

Comment: I know, but they are wrapped down ;) I got an outside scrollbar.

Comment: could you clarify what yuo want to achieve? maybe post a picture of how it should look?

Comment: @Alex i edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xhy28kop/5/)
Is that what you want?
I changed the border-colors so that one can see which element ges where

I added `white-space: nowrap`

```
.gantt-sub-column-wrapper, .gantt-column-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    white-space: nowrap
```

}

and `overflow: auto`

```
.gantt-chart {
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS.

```
.gantt-chart {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```